# Could an ICBM self-destruct?

Tags: icbm, self-destruct

A nuclear country's leadership sends a command to launch an ICBM. It launches.
Is it ever possible to abort attack on designated target if they change their mind?
If yes, for how long? Is it only while the stage is still burning? Is it only until the warhead re-enters the atmosphere?

I assume that a cruise missible could be give self-destruct command, is it ever possible to so with an ICBM?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about space exploration; it's about military weaponry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [There is no self-destruct system on ICBMs](https://www.ucsusa.org/sites/default/files/attach/2015/01/Hair-Trigger%2520FAQ.pdf). This is done to prevent sabotage and to increase performance.

Comment: Please do not answer obviously off topic questions. You even voted to close.

Comment: For newcomers I will quickly answer even off topic questions to get people to stay. They are less likely to stay if it isn't answered. Being that this took all of 60 seconds to write, I think it is a worthwhile investment. @OrganicMarble

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch that just encourages people to *continue to ask off-topic question* though.

Comment: I did downvote and vote to close. I will still be helpful and welcoming to newcomers though, espically if it hardly takes any time. If this user asks another off topic question, I will not answer it. @fyrepenguin

Comment: What @fyrepenguin said... And in my mind, if you are going to take the time to write an answer, you should upvote the question. Just one of my little quirks, I guess, but if I answer a question, I upvote it. It's bizarre to me that someone would answer a question that they voted to close and downvoted.

Comment: It is a bad question. I still answered it as it was a quick answer and may encourage a new user to stay @OrganicMarble

Comment: @OrganicMarble In principle, a question can be both good (upvote) and offtopic (VTC).